# Laravel 5.6 - permission denied on logs/laravel.log ubuntu xenial 16.04

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu, permissions

Have visited topics on this before to no avail - struggling to get rid of a permissions error "Failed to open stream" on logs/laravel.log, the *only* thing that works at the moment is setting directory permissions to 777, that of course in a live server production environment is extremely bad practice.

I've followed practically every tutorial, like this one for example is the most recent I've come across:

https://vijayasankarn.wordpress.com/2017/02/04/securely-setting-file-permissions-for-laravel-framework/

and this

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/

Generally speaking, some checks I've carried out include checking ownership/groups by running

```
ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
```

which returns the following results

```
root      6723  0.0  0.4  77944  4880 ?        Ss   14:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6726  0.0  0.6 432716  6708 ?        Sl   14:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6727  0.0  0.6 432772  6696 ?        Sl   14:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
ubuntu    6874  0.0  0.0  12948   948 pts/0    S+   15:07   0:00 grep -E --color=auto (apache|httpd)
```

So I know my server is owned by www-data - even performing sudo chgrp changes such as ubuntu:www-data had no effect.

I had the same problem in local environment. On production, my blade template is practically rendered as raw text content as opposed to displaying the Laravel error page - assuming it's because the bootstrap/cache (which I've also modified permissions and ownership for) is being unable to be written to/partially written to.

I've also noted that a lot of tutorials mention bootstrap/cache being within the /storage folder but in newer Laravel versions this seems to have moved to /project-directory/bootstrap as opposed to /project-directory/storage/bootstrap etc.

I'm running Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 on an Amazon AWS instance.

Any help would be thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the owner/permissions for storage and logs directories?

Comment: @aynber Sure it outputs this:

`drwxr-xr-x root     root     /
 drwxr-xr-x root     root     var
 drwxr-xr-x root     root     www
 drwxr-xr-x root     root     html
 drwxrwxr-x www-data www-data flexischedule
 drwxrwxr-x ubuntu   www-data storage
 drwxrwxr-x ubuntu   www-data logs`

I've switched between ubuntu and www-data as the owner and still nothing.

Sorry the format is not great in comments

Comment: @logikurl with these commands in your project root you should be good to go `chmod -R 775 storage
chmod 775 bootstrap/cache
chown -R www-data ./`

Comment: The directories are group writeable, but that doesn't always pass down into the folder. They're owned by ubuntu instead of www-data, so that could mess things up a bit. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-framework-file-permission-security has some extended commands that might help.

Comment: @Bart thanks - I tried those commands and a couple of variations to no avail. Still seeing the raw text output of my "welcome" blade template. I figured the `./` would work to pass down the hierarchy but no go.

Comment: @aynber Came across that post before but this time I tried some extended commands, including the `ug+rwx` in the root and passing it down through `sudo chmod 775` and using `./` as @Bart has recommended to pass down into the hierarchy, bafflingly, still rendering the "welcome" template as raw text.

Comment: @Aynber also, permissions are now:

`drwxrwxr-x www-data www-data flexischedule
 drwxrwxr-x www-data www-data storage
 drwxrwxr-x www-data www-data logs`

Everything now belongs to `www-data` and seems fine? But it still doesn't work.

Comment: @logikurl try `chown -R www-data:www-data ./` in your project root. Check, and if it is not working, please add result of your `dir -l` in your project root.

Comment: @Bart done the `chown` still nothing, `dir-l` output is too long to post in the comments but it essentially says `total 660` 

`drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 May 24 10:23 bootstrap`
`drwxrwxr-x+ 5 www-data www-data   4096 May 24 10:23 storage`

Is the output for the directories we've been discussing/mentioned.

Comment: @logikurl check what php version and under what user your php is running?

Comment: @Bart PHP version is `PHP 7.2.5-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)`

If I've got the command right - then running `ps -ef | egrep 'php'` should show the owner of PHP right? If so then the output is showing as:

`ubuntu   14522 14337  0 18:22 pts/0    00:00:00 grep -E --color=auto php`

Shows as Ubuntu, we may be on to something here.

Running `ps aux | egrep '(php)'` also outputs:
`ubuntu   14529  0.0  0.1  12948  1028 pts/0    S+   18:25   0:00 grep -E --color=auto (php)`
`

Comment: @logikurl even more, maybe you are not running php on apache at all? Temporarily change your `public/index.php` contents to `<?php phpinfo();` If it is not rendering php info page, then you need check tutorials on how to properly install and setup apache with php on your server...

Comment: @Bart Thank you so much, you actually led me along the right path, the problem was indeed that for some odd reason, the PHP module was disabled. The `php.conf` and `php.load` files were not to be found in the apache2 `mods-enabled` or `mods-available` folders. I had to manually create those files + content within following another guide and point them to the `libphp7.2.so` file. That + the permissions messages above must have worked because now it's all loading fine :) I went on a rabbit hole journey to enable/configure a bunch of other things but it works!

Comment: @logikurl glad to hear that...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @Bart has led me to figure out. The problem here was a mixture of two things. First was indeed the permissions error, which seems to have been fixed by `chmod` the whole project directory to 755 or 775 after `chgrp` to `www-data` - see comments in original question for guidance on this.

Second due to the fact that I had to reinstall apache at some point after removing it from my original lamp-server installation due to some bad configs, this for some reason, caused my PHP to become disabled on my server and the php files for apache (which I found out were called php.mod and php.load) had gone missing. It was either this or the initial switch and upgrade to 7.2 disabled my PHP (this seems to be a documented Ubuntu bug, reference here https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=893481).

Apache had no mention of any PHP files within it's `mods-enabled` or `mods-available` folders. So I followed the guide here to get this up and running but changed the variables to match my current PHP version which is 7.2 and point it to `libphp7.2.so`.

https://digitizor.com/how-to-fix-module-php5-does-not-exist-error-in-apache-linux/

I also came across some mcrypt related errors for my config, mainly due to the fact that mcrypt is no longer supported on 7.2 as it is no longer maintained and they are phasing it out to make a move towards libsodium, but there were still some dependencies on it I believe.  I installed this via pecl using php-pear.

There were a tonne of other things that were awry that I couldn't possibly document, I highly recommend to anyone reading this, follow a good guide in accordance to your OS and try not to go back/modify your initial core LAMP/WAMP/MAMP etc. setup too much like I did (I think the manual removal of apache2 via purge and then re-install triggered the server side issues to begin with).

Once my PHP was enabled, the text no longer was outputting raw and the permissions changes must have worked as I now see the Laravel default welcome page.

Also on any new installs on "naked" servers - please double check that PHP is enabled for the server system you are using, along with PHP rewrite, mbstring, dev and CLI mods.